# ActiveRecord 3 RC 1 with NHibernate 3.2 causes an unexpected exception

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate

Since I felt adventurous the other day I decided compiling ActiveRecord 3 RC 1 with NHibernate 3.2 and see what happens.
Besides the breaking changes which I fixed I encountered a very strange behavior regarding SessionScopes and Linq queries.
Usually I don't have to use a session scope when using a Linq query but after I compiled ActiveRecord 3 RC 1 with NHibernate 3.2 I got the following error:

```
Could not found a registered Scope. Linq queries needs a underlying a scope to be functional.
Stack Trace:    at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordLinqBase`1.get_Queryable()
   at Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable[T]()
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices.BranchDataService.GetBranches() in D:\Work\Default\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions\DataServices\BranchDataService.cs:line 21
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Controllers.SmallHoursAmountController.<>c__DisplayClassb.<SetBranches>b__a() in D:\Work\Default\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\Controllers\SmallHoursAmountController.cs:line 275
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Viewlets.WaitForAction.Worker_DoWork(Object sender
DoWorkEventArgs e) in D:\Work\Default\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\Viewlets\WaitForAction.cs:line 40
```

It seems that the error comes from here:

```
public class ActiveRecordLinqBase<T> : ActiveRecordBase<T>
{
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Queryable
        {
            get
            {
                var activeScope = holder.ThreadScopeInfo.GetRegisteredScope(); // The registered scope is null...

                if (activeScope == null)
                    throw new ActiveRecordException("Could not found a registered Scope. Linq queries needs a underlying a scope to be functional.");

                var key = holder.GetSessionFactory(typeof(T));

                var session = activeScope.IsKeyKnown(key) ? activeScope.GetSession(key) : SessionFactoryHolder.OpenSessionWithScope(activeScope, key);

                return session.AsQueryable<T>();
            }
        }
    }
```

What has changed that now I have to open a new **SessionScope**?

Comment: and this didn't happen with the same AR and NH 3.1?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer Nope.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: So what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble too with the Queryable function. Although I did not have the sessions scope problem, I had trouble saving update to objects retrieved by IQueryable. It seems that the new session was never registered with the active scope.  I also changed the scope retrieval so maybe this also helps for you:

```
   public new IOrderedQueryable<T> Queryable
    {
        get
        {
            ISessionFactory key = ActiveRecordMediator<T>.GetSessionFactoryHolder().GetSessionFactory(typeof(T));
            ISessionScope activeScope = SessionScope.Current;

            if (activeScope == null)
                throw new ActiveRecordException("Could not found a registered Scope. Linq queries needs a underlying a scope to be functional.");

            var session = activeScope.IsKeyKnown(key) ? activeScope.GetSession(key) : OpenSessionWithScope(activeScope, key);

            if (!activeScope.IsKeyKnown(key))
            {
                activeScope.RegisterSession(key,session);
            }
            return session.AsQueryable<T>();
        }
    }
```